# Sequelize attributes returns all table columns

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I want to select columns to retrieve from table with sequelize using attributes.

But it does not work as expected :

```
messengerModel.findAll({
    attributes: ['message_title']
})
```

This code returns all columns from table :

```
 SELECT `id`, `room_id`, `sender`, `message_id`, `message_source`, `status`, `message_content`, `message_uid`, `recipient`, `conversation`, `mail_date`, `person_id`, `message_title` FROM `messenger`
```

Does somebody encounter this problem ?

I'm using sequelize 6.20.1

Thanks for your help !

Comment: I've come back to this question several times hoping that something will come to me, but it hasn't. The code you've shared should only select the message_title column. I suggest looking elsewhere in your code to try to pinpoint what's going wrong here.

Comment: Check that you don't have any default scopes for this model and also you don't have similar queries

Answer (score -1):

I would advise to make sure the table name is correct.

**Option 2:** I can say check the definition of your messengerModel to ensure that the message_title attribute is correctly defined. The model definition should include all the columns you want to access.

Comment: If the query returns **all** columns, I would assume that the table name is correct. Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Thanks for the comments. You are right but, I see the table name mentioned in the sequelize query and sql query is different.

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your answer** by editing it

Comment: I still don't get your point. The code you've shared looks exactly like the code from the question - did you change anything?

Comment: Nope, I have put the code just for reference. The actual problem could be with the model definition.

Comment: I have deleted option 1, which is wrong. Sorry